# how to dynamically handle multiple lists plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a range of lists with same len, as below:

```
a=[10,56,78,90]
b=[2,8,33,10]
```

And I might need to include a new list, for example.

I have been using the following to plot lists a and b:

```
plt.plot(x,a)
plt.plot(x,b)
```

As you can see, I want to use the same x-axis for both of them.

However, I'd like to figure out how this piece of code should be in order to receive new lists or drop a current list dynamically.

Any thoughts on this?

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to run a loop that plots each list separately and it looks like its moving. To do that, you have to put your lists in a list. For example:

```
l=[a,b];
for i in range(0,len(l):
   plt.plot(x,l[i]);
```

you can add title, legend axis, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

#setup the figure 
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
x=[1,2,3,4]
initial=4*[0]
line1 = plt.plot(x, initial, 'k', lw=1.5, label=0)
plt.title('Dynamic Plotting', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Dynamic List', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=12)

plt.ion()   # set interactive mode
plt.show()


a=[10,56,78,90]
b=[2,8,33,10]
u=[a,b]

#loop over your list
for i,list in enumerate(u):
    for l in line1:
        l.remove()
        del l

    line1 = plt.plot(x, list, 'k', lw=1.5, label=i)
    plt.legend()
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(2)
```